# HybridWebView not firing the LoadFinished event

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on my first Xamarin.IOS application and I would like to retrieve the HTML page loaded in the webview. In order to accomplish this I have referred Google and Xamarin forum and implemented the following steps but still the LoadFinished event is not getting triggered. Can anyone please help me fix this problem.

1. Made the AppDelegate to extend from XFormsApplicationDelegate
2. In the FinishedLaunching event, I have the following set of code

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

SetIoc();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
XLabs.Forms.XFormsAppiOS.Init();
var webHybrid = new XLabs.Forms.Controls.HybridWebViewRenderer();

                return true;
            }

            private void SetIoc()
            {
                var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();

                resolverContainer.Register<IDevice>(t => AppleDevice.CurrentDevice)
                                    .Register<IJsonSerializer, SystemJsonSerializer>()
                                    .Register<IDependencyContainer>(t => resolverContainer);
                Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
            }
```

MyViewController has the following code

```
public partial class MainViewController : UIViewController
{
HybridWebView webview;

        protected MainViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            var webHybrid = new HybridWebViewRenderer();
            webview = new HybridWebView();
        }

        void Webview_LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webview.RegisterCallback("dataCallback", s =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
                    this.webview.LoadFinished -= Webview_LoadFinished;
                    this.webview.RemoveCallback("dataCallback");
                });

            this.webview.InjectJavaScript("Native(\"dataCallback\", document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
        }

        private void GalleryButtonTouchUpAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webview.Uri = new Uri("http://google.co.in");
            webview.LoadFinished += Webview_LoadFinished;   
        }
    }
```

Can you please help what is that I 'm missing?

Comment: If you move webview.LoadFinished += Webview_LoadFinished line to be under this line: webview = new HybridWebView(); The LoadFinished my be called before the event is wired up.

Comment: Hi Adam, I moved the event init code per your suggestion but still the event is not getting fired. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac Preview (Preview 3). Mono 4.8.0, Xamarin.IOS 10.4.0.73 if that helps to narrow down my issue.

Comment: And the page is correctly loading in your WebView? And does it get called at all at any time? I notice that you remove the event handler in the RegisterCallback.

Comment: My intention is to get the HTML of the page after the page is loaded (behind the scene), so I'm not actually displaying the webview to my user. Do you recommend checking the webview with the user interface if that can make any difference?